# Convert String fields to ObjectID fields in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database with two schemas - users and posts. It used to look like this:

```
username: {type: String},
following: {type: [String], ref: 'users'}

user_id: {type: String, ref: 'users'}
comment: {type: String}
```

But now I've decided to change reference fields' types from String to ObjectId so now I have:

```
username: {type: String},
following: {type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'users'}

user_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}
comment: {type: String}
```

But the old data in the database is still stored as Strings. How can I migrate that data properly?

I use Mongoose to query the database from my code.

Comment: Are the strings valid `ObjectId` hex values?

Comment: @chridam Yes, they are.

Comment: i think you shoud use model.find({}) all the post documents and after that loop through each docment and doc. user_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc.user_id); and do doc.save on each document

Comment: Why I typically do is convert my old data with mongo shell script

Comment: @AsifSaeed Thanks, this is what I eventually did.

Comment: @CorrieSparrow you are welcome let me add this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 
model.find({}) to fetch all the post documents and after that loop through each document and update each document

```
doc.user_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc.user_id); 
doc.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use model.find({}) to get all documents and loop through the docs and update it.

````
const media = await Media.find({});
            media.forEach(async (item) => {
            const update = await Media.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: item._id },
                    { user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.user) },
                    { upsert: true }
                );
            });```
````