# How to patch mongoose data with command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema that I want to update and patch all existing data. Old country field is 'String' while the new country field is now 'ObjectId', pointing to a Country Schema. Cant seem to find a solution after a few days. Anyone can help me?

Old schema

```
}
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String }
    ...
}
```

New Schema

```
}
    name: { type: String, require: true },
    country: Schema.Types.ObjectId
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String fields to ObjectID fields in MongoDB using Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911497/convert-string-fields-to-objectid-fields-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

Comment: I did try to do it that way. But once i switched to the new schema, the Model doesn't return the field anymore, since strings are still stored in db.